# Merging different soundtracks

Tags: command-line, sound

I want to merge few audio files into one single track. I have cut the individual parts using online audio cutting tools. How do I merge them into a single track without breaking continuity at all ? I dont know how to mix, balance audio. I want to understand this process. Can anyone help me with the details. I am currently using ubuntu 16.04 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Audacity software. It is open source software and allows multiple track recording, stereo or mono, mixing, and editing the files with filters to add echo or filter noises...
I think you will not be dissapointed. It is very easy to use.

Hope this may help you.

Best regards,

Jose.

Comment: Initially in ubuntu 14.04 I tried using audacity. I couldnt figure out anything. I am aware of the fact that audacity is a great tool but somehow it fails to drive me home. How should I learn Audacity ?